# Is it possible to parse json in Flutter/Dart with missing attributes (keys of json data)?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have list of objects in json form that are coming from an API. These objects have some attributes, the problem is some of the objects have missing attributes. **My Question is:** Is it possible to parse this data in Flutter/Dart or not? **OR** I have to change to API response so no attribute is missing in it.

**JSON DATA:**

```
[
    {
        "names": "Jean lewis  Mbayabu ",
        "users_name": "jeanlewis",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "32",
        "title": "Canada",
        "category": "student"
    },
    {
        "names": "Abhi Vish",
        "users_name": "abhi",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "59",
        "category": "student"
    },
    {
        "names": "Julie Mabengi",
        "users_name": "julie",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "116"
    }
]
```

Comment: Sure, you just need to handle the case where a given `key` does return `null` (by e.g. make the field a nullable).

Comment: @julemand101
I'm trying to parse the data like this:
```SearchedUser.fromJson(dynamic response) {
    return SearchedUser(
      userId: response['id'],
      name: response['names'],
      userName: response['users_name'],
      profileImage: response['avt'],
      title: response['title'],
      category: response['category'],
    );
  }```
Can you please show me an example how can I handle the ```null``` check for ```key```?

Comment: `title: response['title'] ?? 'default title',       category: response['category'] ?? 'default category',`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example on how to do it. I have made `title` or `category` nullable since we don't always has this two fields:

```
import 'dart:convert';

const jsonString = '''
[
    {
        "names": "Jean lewis  Mbayabu ",
        "users_name": "jeanlewis",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "32",
        "title": "Canada",
        "category": "student"
    },
    {
        "names": "Abhi Vish",
        "users_name": "abhi",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "59",
        "category": "student"
    },
    {
        "names": "Julie Mabengi",
        "users_name": "julie",
        "avt": "Image URL",
        "id": "116"
    }
]
''';

class SearchedUser {
  final String names;
  final String users_name;
  final String avt;
  final int id;
  final String? title;
  final String? category;

  const SearchedUser(
      {required this.names,
      required this.users_name,
      required this.avt,
      required this.id,
      required this.title,
      required this.category});

  factory SearchedUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SearchedUser(
      names: json['names'] as String,
      users_name: json['users_name'] as String,
      avt: json['avt'] as String,
      id: int.parse(json['id'] as String),
      title: json['title'] as String?,
      // title: json['title'] ?? "defaultTitle", // default title if field is absent or null
      category: json['category'] as String?);
      // category: json['category'] ?? "defaultCategory"); // default category if field is absent or null

  @override
  String toString() => 'names: $names, '
      'users_name: $users_name, '
      'avt: $avt, '
      'id: $id, '
      'title: $title, '
      'category: $category';
}

void main() {
  final jsonList = jsonDecode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>;
  final searchedUsers = [
    for (final map in jsonList.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>())
      SearchedUser.fromJson(map)
  ];

  searchedUsers.forEach(print);
  // names: Jean lewis  Mbayabu , users_name: jeanlewis, avt: Image URL, id: 32, title: Canada, category: student
  // names: Abhi Vish, users_name: abhi, avt: Image URL, id: 59, title: null, category: student
  // names: Julie Mabengi, users_name: julie, avt: Image URL, id: 116, title: null, category: null
}
```