# Flutter conditional statement with output of jsondecode var

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, conditional-statements, openweathermap

I want to show different images for different outputs of JSONdecode. I get var between 01d and 50d. For example, when it gives out 04d, I want to show Image 'assets/night.png' and for 05d, I want to show Image 'assets/afternoon.png' and more. *I am a complete beginner with flutter, this is what I thought about:*

```
var current_icon;

  Future getWeather () async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=city&appid=****"));
    var results = jsonDecode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      this.current_icon = results['weather'][0]['icon'];
    });
  }
@override
  void initState () {
    super.initState();
    this.getWeather();
  }
```

and then put it in my container here:

```
new Container(
    height: double.infinity,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: new Image(
          image: (What should I do here?),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
       ),
    ),
```

Comment: Use conditional statement (ie. if - else if or switch) and return image data based on your requirement and pass to your image widget

Comment: But how should I do that? Can you give me some code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your query assuming all images comes from assets. You can make cases as per your requirement like this:

```
String getImageData(String id) {
    String value = '';
    switch (id) {
      case '01d':
        value = 'assets/a.png';
        break;
      case '02d':
        value = 'assets/b.png';
        break;
      default:
        value = 'assets/c.png';
    }
    return value;
  }
```

pass below widget as child of your container widget

```
Widget imageWidget() {
    return Image.asset(
      getImageData('01d'), // pass your value here
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, but isn't it showing the same every time? Like, now it is showing 01d, which is great, but in this moment the output of the decode is 04d. Can you help me again?

Comment: You need to pass the output of your `jsonDecode` to `getImageData`. So instead of `getImageData('01d')`, do `getImageData(current_icon)`.

Comment: @Cubii you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem

Comment: I didn't know that I have to do that, here you go. Another little question: When I navigate to the page it shows a red screen saying *type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'* for a second. Do you have an idea how I could fix that?

Comment: @Cubii Might this helps you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955033/type-string-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-null-in-get-method-flutter